# SharePoint Designer workflow not sending email to "Everyone"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I have a requirement where in, I have to send an email to everyone from SPD workflow.
I have put to Everyone, cc to abc (a normal user).

Email is received only by the abc not no one else.

How to send an email to everyone in the organization from SharePoint designer workflow? (SharePoint 2013, SPD 2010 workflow)

Answer (score 0):

You have the provision to send emails either to specific users or SharePoint Groups as part of a Designer Workflow. **Everyone** is not an email enabled entity.

One option is to create a **SharePoint Group** and add all the users to the Group and then use this group as the Email recipient.

Comment: Adding all users to the group is a nightmare, there are 200+ users and every month new people join/leave. It's not possible to maintain this way.

Comment: You'll need to manage the group on the AD/email list side, not the SharePoint side. Everyone is open to everyone, but is not a list of everyone, so it cannot be used for emailing.